# Ubuntu 17.04 systemd-resolved configuration

Tags: dns, 17.04, systemd-resolved

I use Ubuntu for development. 
And I've build my dev env with using `dnsmasq` for resolving my dev hostnames, usually it's:

```
<projectname>.dev.net
```

So I set up my own DNS server for getting proper IP address (I'm using docker)

I used to create conf file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` with content:

`server=/dev.net/172.18.0.1`

Thus `dnsmasq` redirects all `dns-resolve` request to `172.18.0.1` for `*.dev.net` domains.

How can I configure the same behaviour for resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to configure different upstream servers for i.e. `dev.net` with `systemd-resolved.service`

What worked for me (on Ubuntu 17.04) is to install and configure a `dnsmasq` server alongside the `systemd-resolved.service`

The steps needed would be:

**package installation:**

```
apt install dnsmasq -y
```

**start and enable dnsmasq service:**

```
systemctl start dnsmasq
systemctl enable dnsmasq
```

**add a configuration file inside `/etc/dnsmasq.d/` like this:**

```
server=/dev.net/172.18.0.1
```

Comment: I am planning to disable `systemd-resolved` as well.
Thank you for confirming there is no chances to make it workable with desired configuration.

Answer (score 3):

it is *now* possible, under ubuntu 18.04 (systemd --version -> 237) to configure dns per link:
sudo systemd-resolve --interface lxdbr0 --set-dns 10.11.0.1 --set-domain lxd

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is how I resolved this:

First, installed `dnsmasq`:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

added `dns=dnsmasq` to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`'s `[main]` section.

Edited `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to add:

```
DNS=127.0.1.1
FallbackDNS=127.0.1.1
```

in the `[Resolve]` section.

Copy all needed configuration to `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/`.

After `reboot` everything should be fine (or just restart `NetworkManager` & `systemd-resolved`).